# JS/jQuery array looping thumbnails using next and previous image arrows for navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement, thumbnails

I'm fairly new to arrays and I was interested in using it to control a series of thumbnail positions whenever a next or previous arrow is pressed.  Additionally these thumbs should loop whenever an image completes a cycle across the array. I used a series of if/else statements and splice to add and remove thumbs that needed to be recycled.

I was successful at getting the Next button to accomplish the task I was working to achieve, but I cannot seem to get the Previous button to behave the same way and reverse the thumbnail flow in the opposite direction.  I've tried many different things, but have had no success.

```js
// find elements
var $galleryThumbs = $('#galleryThumbs');
var $galleryThumbsWrapper = $('#galleryThumbsWrapper');
var $next = $('#nextBtn');
var $prev = $('#prevBtn');

var $thumb01 = $('.thumb#t01');
var $thumb02 = $('.thumb#t02');
var $thumb03 = $('.thumb#t03');
var $thumb04 = $('.thumb#t04');
var $thumb05 = $('.thumb#t05');
var $thumb06 = $('.thumb#t06');
var $thumb07 = $('.thumb#t07');

// handle click and add class
var pic = new Array();
pic = [$thumb05, $thumb06, $thumb07, $thumb01, $thumb02, $thumb03, $thumb04];

var x = $($galleryThumbsWrapper);

var thumbOrder = 0;

function checkNextOrder(thumbOrder) {
  x.css('float', 'left');
  if (thumbOrder == 0) {
    console.log("thumbOrder == 0");
    pic.splice(0, 1, $thumb04);
    x.append($thumb04);
    return thumbOrder;

  } else if (thumbOrder == 1) {
    console.log("thumbOrder == 1");
    pic.splice(0, 1, $thumb05);
    x.append($thumb05);
    return thumbOrder;

  } else if (thumbOrder == 2) {
    console.log("thumbOrder == 2");
    pic.splice(0, 1, $thumb06);
    x.append($thumb06);
    return thumbOrder;

  } else if (thumbOrder == 3) {
    console.log("thumbOrder == 3");
    pic.splice(0, 1, $thumb07);
    x.append($thumb07);
    return thumbOrder;

  } else if (thumbOrder == 4) {
    console.log("thumbOrder == 4");
    pic.splice(0, 1, $thumb01);
    x.append($thumb01);
    return thumbOrder;

  } else if (thumbOrder == 5) {
    console.log("thumbOrder == 5");
    pic.splice(0, 1, $thumb02);
    x.append($thumb02);
    return thumbOrder;

  } else if (thumbOrder == 6) {
    console.log("thumbOrder == 6");
    pic.splice(0, 1, $thumb03);
    x.append($thumb03);
    return thumbOrder;
  }
}



function checkPrevOrder(thumbOrder) {
  x.css('float', 'right');
  console.log('previous');
  if (thumbOrder == 6) {
    console.log("thumbOrder == 6");
    pic.splice(6, 1, $thumb04);
    x.append($thumb04);
    return thumbOrder;
  } else if (thumbOrder == 5) {
    console.log("thumbOrder == 5");
    pic.splice(6, 1, $thumb03);
    x.append($thumb03);
    return thumbOrder;
  } else if (thumbOrder == 4) {
    pic.splice(6, 1, $thumb02);
    x.append($thumb02);
    return thumbOrder;
  } else if (thumbOrder == 3) {
    console.log("thumbOrder == 3");
    pic.splice(6, 1, $thumb01);
    x.append($thumb01);
    return thumbOrder;
  } else if (thumbOrder == 2) {
    console.log("thumbOrder == 2");
    pic.splice(6, 1, $thumb07);
    x.append($thumb07);
    return thumbOrder;
  } else if (thumbOrder == 1) {
    console.log("thumbOrder == 1");
    pic.splice(6, 1, $thumb06);
    x.append($thumb06);
    return thumbOrder;
  } else if (thumbOrder == 0) {
    console.log("thumbOrder == 0");
    pic.splice(6, 1, $thumb05);
    x.append($thumb05);
    return thumbOrder;
  }
}

$($next).on('click', function() {
  console.log('next');
  console.log("Thumborder is currently at:" + thumbOrder);
  if (thumbOrder < 6) {
    thumbOrder++;
    checkNextOrder(thumbOrder);
  } else {
    thumbOrder = 0;
    checkNextOrder(thumbOrder);
  }
})



$($prev).on('click', function() {
  console.log('prev');
  if (thumbOrder > 0) {
    thumbOrder--;
    checkPrevOrder(thumbOrder);
  } else {
    thumbOrder = 6;
    checkPrevOrder(thumbOrder);
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#galleryThumbs {
  position: absolute;
  width: 769px;
  height: 90px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 256px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  padding-left: 2px;
}

#galleryThumbsWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1078px;
  height: 90px;
  left: -153px;
}

.thumb {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.thumb img {
  width: 70%;
}

#nextBtn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  left: 800px;
  top: 112px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nextBtn img {
  width: 50%;
}

#prevBtn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  left: 52px;
  top: 112px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#prevBtn img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="galleryThumbs">
  <div id="galleryThumbsWrapper">
    <div class="thumb" id="t05"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UCgERDCYii8/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLCfo2vTp1vra68dAfNSADkAjA_P1w"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t06"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Fj8G9dGuNkU/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLAtZua5DkREddQL16of68eZ-9uM7w"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t07"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9BjvxQnk0qA/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLAsBtUg6iahpBrriWLcBhVLnaDrYg"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t01"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TCkmKgUp1ak/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLAR6VNzvmxfP3Q7Hzuj2721PD4cGg"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t02"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/p0t0J_ERzHM/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLBAp9YZP9Ktnvf2n0T0kgYgmlvCYg"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t03"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/L-s_h5PS7VQ/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLA2peKpky-S2clFMM2QDepYL1fumw"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t04"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CCb_XbmB_iE/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLC2hr7_n6PMmBiqHshY1AotfE4lSg"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id='nextBtn'><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_right_alt1-512.png"></div>
<div id='prevBtn'><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_left_alt1-512.png"></div>
```

I have laid out my issue above for review.  If anyone has a more simple/elegant way of solving this, your feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to pluck off the element using [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) and reinserting it back into the dom using a combination of [`.first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) with [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) &[`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) with [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) depending on the direction.

```js
// find elements
var $galleryThumbsWrapper = $('#galleryThumbsWrapper');
var $next = $('#nextBtn');
var $prev = $('#prevBtn');

$prev.on('click', function () {
  // $('.thumb') grabs all divs with that class
  // grab first element using .first 
  // then detach from dom and append to the end
  var $firstItem = $('.thumb').first().detach();
  $galleryThumbsWrapper.append($firstItem);
});

$next.on('click', function () {
  // grab last element using .last 
  // then detach from dom and prepend to the front
  var $lastItem = $('.thumb').last().detach();
  $galleryThumbsWrapper.prepend($lastItem);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#galleryThumbs {
  position: absolute;
  width: 769px;
  height: 90px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 256px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  padding-left: 2px;
}

#galleryThumbsWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1078px;
  height: 90px;
  left: -153px;
}

.thumb {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.thumb img {
  width: 70%;
}

#nextBtn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  left: 800px;
  top: 112px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nextBtn img {
  width: 50%;
}

#prevBtn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  left: 52px;
  top: 112px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#prevBtn img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="galleryThumbs">
  <div id="galleryThumbsWrapper">
    <div class="thumb" id="t05"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UCgERDCYii8/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLCfo2vTp1vra68dAfNSADkAjA_P1w"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t06"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Fj8G9dGuNkU/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLAtZua5DkREddQL16of68eZ-9uM7w"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t07"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9BjvxQnk0qA/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLAsBtUg6iahpBrriWLcBhVLnaDrYg"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t01"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TCkmKgUp1ak/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLAR6VNzvmxfP3Q7Hzuj2721PD4cGg"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t02"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/p0t0J_ERzHM/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLBAp9YZP9Ktnvf2n0T0kgYgmlvCYg"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t03"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/L-s_h5PS7VQ/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLA2peKpky-S2clFMM2QDepYL1fumw"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t04"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CCb_XbmB_iE/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLC2hr7_n6PMmBiqHshY1AotfE4lSg"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id='nextBtn'><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_right_alt1-512.png"></div>
<div id='prevBtn'><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_left_alt1-512.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this code can refactoring using objects. Check this out:

```js
var pic = [$('.thumb#t05'), $('.thumb#t06'),  $('.thumb#t07'), $('.thumb#t01'), $('.thumb#t02'), $('.thumb#t03'), $('.thumb#t04')];
var x = $('#galleryThumbsWrapper');
var thumbOrder = 0;

var obj = {
    0 : pic[6],
    1 : pic[0],
    2 : pic[1], 
    3 : pic[2],
    4 : pic[3],
    5:  pic[4],
    6 : pic[5]
};


function checkNextOrder(thumbOrder){
   pic.splice(0, 1, obj[thumbOrder]);
   x.append(obj[thumbOrder]);
  return thumbOrder;
}

var obj2 = {
    6 : pic[6],
    5 : pic[5],
    4 : pic[4],
    3 : pic[3],
    2 : pic[2],
    1 : pic[1],
    0 : pic[0],
};

function checkPrevOrder(thumbOrder){
    x.css('float','right');
    
   pic.splice(6, 1, obj2[thumbOrder]);
   x.append(obj2[thumbOrder]);
   return thumbOrder;     
}

$('#nextBtn').on('click', function() {
  if(thumbOrder < 6)
    thumbOrder++;
  else
    thumbOrder = 0;
  checkNextOrder(thumbOrder);
});


$('#prevBtn').on('click', function() {
  if(thumbOrder > 0)
    thumbOrder--;
  else
    thumbOrder = 6;
  checkPrevOrder(thumbOrder);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#galleryThumbs {
  position: absolute;
  width: 769px;
  height: 90px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 256px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  padding-left: 2px;
}

#galleryThumbsWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1078px;
  height: 90px;
  left: -153px;
}

.thumb {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.thumb img {
  width: 70%;
}

#nextBtn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  left: 800px;
  top: 112px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nextBtn img {
  width: 50%;
}

#prevBtn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  left: 52px;
  top: 112px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#prevBtn img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="galleryThumbs">
  <div id="galleryThumbsWrapper">
    <div class="thumb" id="t05"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UCgERDCYii8/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLCfo2vTp1vra68dAfNSADkAjA_P1w"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t06"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Fj8G9dGuNkU/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLAtZua5DkREddQL16of68eZ-9uM7w"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t07"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9BjvxQnk0qA/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLAsBtUg6iahpBrriWLcBhVLnaDrYg"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t01"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TCkmKgUp1ak/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLAR6VNzvmxfP3Q7Hzuj2721PD4cGg"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t02"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/p0t0J_ERzHM/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLBAp9YZP9Ktnvf2n0T0kgYgmlvCYg"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t03"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/L-s_h5PS7VQ/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLA2peKpky-S2clFMM2QDepYL1fumw"></div>
    <div class="thumb" id="t04"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CCb_XbmB_iE/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLC2hr7_n6PMmBiqHshY1AotfE4lSg"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='nextBtn'><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_right_alt1-512.png"></div>
<div id='prevBtn'><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_left_alt1-512.png"></div>
```

Comment: I like your idea here, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work when I run the code snippet.

Comment: It was a little problem when click prev or next button. You can check this out now

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to hard code all `$thumb`.

Here is my simpler solution: https://jsfiddle.net/9bdj5mnx/